# Ruby on Rails - reCaptcha

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recaptcha

I have added "<%= recaptcha_tags %>" in Views/Layouts/page2.erb file, but how can I enable the post back in Controller? Tried to follow the tutorial, but doesn't work well.

```
<%= form_for(@schedule, :html => {:class => "form form-label-top container-fluid w-660", :role => "form"}, url: path, method: :post) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'language', f: f %>
  <%= render 'page1', f: f %>
  <%= render 'page2', f: f %>
<% end %>
```

the tag is added in page2

controller code -

```
def create
    @schedule = Schedule.new(rparams)
    if verify_recaptcha(model: @schedule) && @schedule.save
      // success
    else
      // failed
    end
  end
```

Comment: Have you created the captcha initializer with site_key and secret_key and have you added the specific domain that you want to be displayed?

Comment: yes, the thing is showing fine, but just not posting back to controller for validation

Comment: Very strange, I used it yesterday on a rails 5.2 app, followed the exact steps from repository of creating a recaptcha v2 and everything worked fine. https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha

Try to add a breakpoint before the if statement, what it returns? True or false?

Comment: will try to debug and see how it goes